# Qt Phonon on Linux - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, phonon

The following includes work fine in Windows but is giving errors in Linux:

```
#include <Phonon/MediaObject>
#include <Phonon/MediaSource>
#include <Phonon/AudioOutput>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is MediaOutput? I can't find it even in the documentation. Maybe you're looking for MediaObject?

For the rest:

1. check your build actually contains the phonon module;
2. check you added QT += phonon in the .pro file;
3. in my build the directory containing those headers is "phonon" (without the quotes), with the lower case "p", and Linux is not case insensitive like windows.

Comment: Lowercase 'p' was the issue, Thanks!